# macOS shutdown flow

Tags: macos, shutdown, launchd

I'm trying to get a shutdown callback before the kernel take action (meaning, when `Launchd` starts killing all services)

However, it seems that Apple documentation is a little vague in this area, and rather contradicting.

from one hand, according to [power management manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/PowerMgmt/PowerMgmt.html) it's states that the kernel kills the user-space tasks:

> Note: There are other places that you may run code on the shutdown path. For example, if your software has a user-space daemon that runs until shutdown, that daemon can catch SIGTERM, which the kernel sends to all processes at shutdown. In general, try to run your shutdown code as early as possible in the shutdown path.

on the other hand, if you look at the [daemon life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Lifecycle.html) it says that the `loginWindow` is responsible of killing the service.

> For background processes, the procedure is a little different. The loginwindow program notifies the process that it is about to be terminated by sending it a Quit Application Apple event (kAEQuitApplication). Unlike foreground processes, however, loginwindow does not wait for a reply. It proceeds to terminate any open background processes by sending a SIGKILL signal, regardless of any returned errors.
>
> If the system is being shut down or restarted, it sends a SIGTERM signal to all daemons, followed a few seconds later by SIGKILL signal.

Perhaps there's a descent explanation for this contradiction ?

EDIT:

while testing the actual implication on Deamon during shutdown flow, it turns out that it gets a SIGKILL only from `launchd` - I could figure it out as my signal handler for SIGTERM hasn't been called.

Comment: There's no contradiction. The part about `SIGKILL` is talking about user processes, not daemons.

Comment: Hi, I've tested it and proved that the launchd is the entity that send the SIGKILL events to all living daemons, does launchd referred as kernel process ? I know there's an ad-hoc kernel process with pid =0 while launchd is the first user-space process with pid = 1

Comment: Why does it matter where it's sent from?

Comment: I just want to get better understanding of the shutdown flow .. it doesn't make sense that kernel sends signal to user-land services .. launchd is in charge of monitoring this services (in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`) so it should be the one who eventually terminates them.. however, I also noticed that I don't get SIGTERM prior to SIGKILL, any idea why ?

Comment: I just mention that my daemon has plist and it's listed in `launchctl list` in the following record `2152    78      com.zohar.my-daemon`

Comment: It could be both. The kernel has to do something if there's a problem with `launchd`.

Comment: ok that's seems reasonable, thanks.. any idea why am I not getting the SIGTERM first ? is it wrong plist configuration ? I made sure that I don't have the flag `NSSupportsSuddenTermination`

Comment: Nope, no idea. This isn't really a programming question, it's more about the design of OS X. Maybe apple.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask?